# VBA Find Function That Does Not Return Values of Zero

Tags: excel, vba, find

I have a table with Ticker Symbols (A), workdays over the course of a year (B), opening value (C), high value (D), low value (E), closing value (F), and volume (E). The data is chronological by workday and alphabetical by Ticker Symbol (yes, it is related to a previous question I submitted).

I am trying to run a sub routine that will look up the first row number a ticker symbol appears (the opening value for the year). Using the corresponding row and column number, pull the opening value. Then use that value to create a percentage based on a yearly delta that I have created in a separate column.

The below code works fine until there is a portion of the table that has a 0 as the opening value. The related ticker symbol doesn't have a non-zero price appear until later on in the table (IPO for the ticker symbol happens in the middle of the year for example...). My hope was that there would be an easy IF statement that would account for this and pull the first non-zero value for the ticker symbol that is being looked up.

From other questions online, I've only found solutions where you index or match to values in the column not equal to zero. But the way I find if there is a 0 is referencing the first row number a ticker appears... I haven't found a way to incorporate any other solutions into my code.

```
Sub Percent()
'Column Header
Cells(1, 11).Value = "Percent Change"

'Set dims
Dim Summary_Table_Row3 As Integer
Summary_Table_Row3 = 2
LastRow3 = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

'Find start row with unique Ticker
Dim TickStartRow As Double

'Loop through all unique tickers
For I = 2 To LastRow3

  'Find start row
  TickStartRow = Range("A:A").Find(what:=Cells(I, 9), after:=Range("A1"), 
  LookAt:=xlWhole).Row

    'If the yearly change is 0, set percentage to 0
    If Cells(I, 10) = 0 Then
    Cells(I, 11) = 0

    '''ElseIf statement to find first non-zero value if opening value = 0 ?

    'Create percentage for all other non-zero percentages
    Else
    Cells(I, 11) = Cells(I, 10) / Cells(TickStartRow, 3)

    End If

  Cells(I, 11).NumberFormat = "0.00%"

  'Add one to the summary table row
  Summary_Table_Row1 = Summary_Table_Row1 + 1

Next I

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.Find` will only work with visible cells, so for your case, it might be easier to just programmatically apply an `.AutoFilter` and filter out values with 0 just before you fire off your `.Find` functions.

Something like

```
If Worksheets(1).AutoFilterMode = False Then 'Replace Worksheets(1) with a reference to your sheet
    Worksheets(1).Cells.AutoFilter
End If

Worksheets(1).Range("A:Z").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="<>0" 'Again, replace Worksheets(1) and Range("A:Z") with applicable values
```

Just before your `For-Next` loop would work. Then just take the filter off with

```
Cells.AutoFilter
```

Outside of the end of the loop.

**EDIT:**

If you haven't worked with `.AutoFilter` before, it's worth noting that the `Field` criteria for `.AutoFilter` is a relative index based on the range specified. That is to says that `Field:=1` for `Range("A:B")` would apply a filter on Column A, but `Field:=1` for `Range("F:G")` would apply a filter on Column F.

Comment: Simple, yet effective. Thank you, once again.